# Kafka Broker leader change without effect

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 3 kafka brokers, with 3 partitions :

> broker.id 1001: 10.18.0.73:9092 LEADER
>
> broker.id 1002: 10.18.0.73:9093
>
> broker.id 1005: 10.18.0.73:9094
>
> Zookeeper set with 127.0.0.1:2181

Launch with:

```
1001 -> .\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
1002 -> .\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server1.properties
1005 -> .\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server2.properties
```

This is server.properties

```
broker.id=-1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.18.0.73:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.18.0.73:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=10.18.0.73:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
advertised.port=9092
advertised.host.name=10.18.0.73
port=9092
```

This is server1.properties

```
broker.id=-1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.18.0.73:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.18.0.73:9093
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs4
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
advertised.port=9093
advertised.host.name=10.18.0.73
port=9093
```

This is server2.properties

```
broker.id=-1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.18.0.73:9094
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.18.0.73:9094
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs2
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
advertised.port=9094
advertised.host.name=10.18.0.73
port=9094
```

in folder C:\kafka_2.12-2.4.0\config

Run All

[image]

Run Producer

```
.\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list 10.18.0.73:9092,10.18.0.73:9093,10.18.0.73:9094 --topic clinicaleventmanager
```

Run Consumer

```
.\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server 10.18.0.73:9092,10.18.0.73:9093,10.18.0.73:9094 --topic clinicaleventmanager
```

I launch a test message

[image]

Receive ok!

Now, i shutdown broker 1001 (the leader)

[image]

The new leader is 1002

[image]

In the consumer this message appeared for 1 second, I imagine for the time necessary for the election of the new leader

```
[2020-01-16 15:33:35,802] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-56669-1, groupId=console-consumer-56669] Connection to node 2147482646 (/10.18.0.73:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

if I try to send another message, this is not read by the consume
[image]

**The new leader 1002 does not appear to be sending messages.
Why**?

If i run 1001 broker.id, works all.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Kafka never "sends (pushes) messages", the consumer asks for them.

Second, it would seem you've changed nothing but the listeners, port, and log dir.

You don't explicitly create any topic, so you would end up with the defaults of one partition and one replica. For your topic **and the internal consumer offsets topic**

If any replica is offline from the broker you stopped, then no other process can read (or write) to that replica, regardless of which broker is the controller.

So, change the offsets (and transactions) replication factor to 3 and try again

Comment: thanks, but I know that kafka does not automatically send messages to the consumer.
I have modified the properties offsets.topic.replication.factor = 2
default.replication.factor = 2 and it worked.
Thank!